# Where to store the ssh public key for connecting GitLab to Bitbucket?

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, gitlab, public-key, gitlab-omnibus

I'd like to connect (an Omnibus install of) GitLab to Bitbucket. According to [the documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/bitbucket.html#step-1-public-key), I need to create and store a public key for it:

> GitLab will automatically register your public key with Bitbucket as a
>   deploy key for the repositories to be imported. Your public key needs
>   to be at ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa.pub, which will expand to
>   /home/git/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa.pub in most configurations.

The fact is I don't have a `/home/git`. How could I know, then, where I must create the public key, so that GitLab notices it and registers it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home directory for the git User in an Omnibus install is by default `/var/opt/gitlab`. You can either check your `gitlab.rb` config file for the key `user['home']` and see if you have modified it or do a `cat /etc/passwd`and find the home diretory for the user git there.

Default value `user['home']`(remember the # means it is commented out):

`# user['home'] = "/var/opt/gitlab"`

Output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep git`:

`git:x:1000:1000:git,,,:/var/opt/gitlab:/bin/sh`

Once you have found out where the home directory for the user git is, you can put `bitbucket_rsa.pub` in the folder `.ssh`. If it doesn't exist you can create that folder.